# Why does chrome not recognize this manifest.json file?

Tags: json, google-chrome

Here is my `manifest.json` file

```
{
    "name":"Name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description":"This is the description",
    "manifest-version": 2
}
```

Chrome says

> manifest file is missing or unreadable

The file is indeed a **`.json`** file, rather than a .txt file. What is wrong with my manifest.json file?

Comment: You need the brackets []

Answer (score 0):

**manifest file is missing or unreadable**

You have `manifest-json` instead of `manifest_json` in the code snippet.

If you follow [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple) then it lists the simple `manifest.json` for chrome extension. In below snippet replace name, description, icon, url with your own and give it a try.

```
{
  "name": "Great App Name",
  "description": "Pithy description (132 characters or less, no HTML)",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://mysubdomain.example.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://mysubdomain.example.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Let us know, if you have any difficulty in following the tutorial.